# Magento 2 product images not showing, 2 different directories

Tags: magento2, product-images, 404-page

Magento2 is looking directly in the root folder for media and static files. It is not looking in pub/media folder. Product images are not showing in the front. I installed Magento 2 in a subdirectory and with the installation.

I imported the products with Storemanager Emagicone, images were in import file (in root/media and pub/media because i did not know which to use),

Product images are in the front referring to a wrong path:

```
/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/400x533/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/y/o/yorkshire
```

When I look in FTP, the images are in *pub*/media/catalog/product. The above-mentioned directory is totally empty.

Moving the files from root/pub/media to root/media solved partially the problem. All basic images show up, but product images are not showing at all.

**I already tried:**`php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`and `php bin/magento cache:clean` and `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

The file permissions and user owner are OK, also i `deleted all from ROOT > pub > static > EXCEPT .HTACCESS`. I also deleted folder in: `pub/static
var/cache, var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/ , ..source/frontend`

I also looked in `di.xml` `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

**No symlinks!**

Comment: Did you manage to fix this. Please provide the answer.

Comment: Did you check your store configuration? I guess you didnt set your media path or even when, false.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but the document root should point to `<magento root>/pub`.

Answer (score 9):

For individual product, try saving the product in admin without any change.

For all products, try running the following command (this will take some time to complete):

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Comment: I am facing with error in Magento 2.3.4: `Notice: Undefined index: keep_aspect_ratio in vendor/magento/module-media-storage/Service/ImageResize.php on line 308`

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure to double check owner and group of **pub/media** directory.

You may run this command from magento root directory:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R pub/media
```

Assuming **www-data** is used as *Apache* user.

Apache user should have permissions to a pub/media/catalog/product directory to create resized product image files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried it but got Required file '/var/www/html/pub/media/catalog/product/watermark/ ' does not exists.

Answer (score 2):

1) Open `di.xml` from `app\etc\di.xml`

2) Search by `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` and use word Copy instead of Symlink so the final string will be

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

3) Save this file and remove everything from `pub/static` except `.htacess`

4) Through CMD. Clear your cache
5) Flush your cache
6) Do Reindexing

This time, images should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything but no luck. This article finally helped me fix issue

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002446014-Product-images-are-not-displayed-although-set-on-the-Product-Edit-page

All you need to do is login to your db via phpMyAdmin (or similar), go to catalog_product_entity_varchar, search for records with value LIKE "no", you will find that few images may have no_selection as their value. Just remove all of those records.

Images should then display correctly

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try: php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

If You're using watermarks, ensure those are also in place in pub/media/catalog/watermark/default

Comment: Sometimes running the Image Resize Function ensures that the Product Images are properly generated, and in some cases where watermarks are used, missing water6mark files will break the images being made.

Answer (score 0):

php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento c:f