# Magento 2 Related Product Image is not Accurate

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, image

In Related Product Slider,
All Images are of different size and default Magento is not resizing them.
**Screenshot : https://prnt.sc/oax7yl**

[image]
I want to show all images of the same size.

In `view.xml`, I have added the width and height of Image but not worked.

```
<image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
              <width>240</width>
              <height>300</height>
            </image>
```

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/173756/73212

Comment: I tried it by run php bin/magento catalog:images:resize this command aswell but no luck :( @MohitRane

Comment: have you set the images to Base, Small, Thumbnail like shown in the screenshot ?https://nimb.ws/yd8Dex

Comment: @MohitRane yes it is already set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solve the issue:-

```
<?php
$objectManager =\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$helperImport = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$imageUrl = $helperImport->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')
->setImageFile($_product->getFile()) // image,small_image,thumbnail
->resize(300)
->getUrl();
?>
```

I used this code because the issue not solved after doing changes in view.xml.

Answer (score 1):

for this, you have to upload the image of the same dimensions for all products you want if you upload the image of different dimension it will create this issue. this issue can be solved by CSS but it is not recommended because some time image might get stretched out so the best solution is to upload the image of the same dimensions for all products

Answer (score 0):

For individual product, try saving the product in admin without any change.

For all products, try running the following command (this will take some time to complete):

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Comment: this is the copy of @MohitRane comment. Please someone mark it as copy. I don't know how to mark it.